# How to apply Data oriented paradigm when I code gameplay

Tags: c#, unityscript

I am currently thinking about how to apply Data Oriented Design instead of Object Oriented Design.

I have read a lot of articles about DOD, each of them talked about how to apply DOD, why apply DOD, explaining that DOD is not the Silver Bullet against all problems...

But I'm asking myself: what if it could be possible to apply this mindset when I want to code gameplay, when I want to code everything, what it could offer, to what extend this mindset could limit me ?

This week I talked about a gameplay feature with my teacher, and he explained me that DOD mindset is basically Data, and Functions, every data is a universe, and each function is a way of go from a universe to another (this metaphor can seem to be strange but it sounds good, when you have an animation all universes are every position of your skeleton in the timeline, the way to make a transition between them is to apply an easing function).

I don't really know how to apply it, what will I Lose if tried to apply Data Oriented Design instead of Object Oriented Design, do you have a concrete code example to explain me how to apply it ?

Answer (score 0):

Array Of Struct(AOS), maybe lead to cache miss, ParticleSystem is very suitable for DOD(data oriented)，that is AOS ronvert to SOA.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

the original system is AOS, the struct is:

```
class TextureParticle
{
public:
    friend class TextureParticleEmitter;
public:
Vector3     mPosition;
Vector3     mLastPosition;
Vector3     mVelocity;
Vector2     mUVOffset;
Color       mColor;
Color       mBaseColor;
Float       mRandom;
Float       mScale;
Float       mBaseScale;
Float       mRotate;
};
TextureParticle particles[PARTILCE_COUNT];
```

update:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < PARTICLE_COUNT; i++)
updateParticle(particles[i]);
```

when convert AOS to SOA,the struct is :

```
class TextureParticles
{
public:
    float*          mRemainLife;
    Vector3*            mPosition;
Vector3*            mVelocity;
Vector2*            mUVOffset;
Color*              mColor;
Float*              mRandom;
Float*              mScale;
Float*              mRotate;
};
```

everytime the ParticleSystem update,not all Attribute update, but the single attribute in all .

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < ParticleCount ; ++i)
    UpdatePositions;
for(int i = 0 ; i < ParticleCount ; ++i)
    UpdateVelocity;
  ....
  ....
```